# Building pygame game with buildozer causes fatal error

Tags: python, android, pygame, buildozer

When building pygame (2.5.2) with buildozer (1.5.0) on python (3.10.12) the error attached occurs.
It happens when building pygame for armeabi-v7a.

The command ran was `buildozer -v android debug`

I am following this tutorial: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L6XOqakZOeA](https://stackoverflow.com)

```
fatal error: 'longintrepr.h' file not found
  #include "longintrepr.h"
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.

---
For help with compilation see:
    https://www.pygame.org/wiki/Compilation
To contribute to pygame development see:
    https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
---

error: command '/home/captaindeathead/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1


  STDERR:

# Command failed: ['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pythonforandroid.toolchain', 'create', '--dist_name=myapp', '--bootstrap=sdl2', '--requirements=python3,pygame,jnius,sdl2,sdl2_image,sdl2_mixer,sdl2_ttf,png,jpeg', '--arch=arm64-v8a', '--arch=armeabi-v7a', '--copy-libs', '--color=always', '--storage-dir=/media/captaindeathead/HardDrive/PythonProjects/Farm_CEO/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a', '--ndk-api=21', '--ignore-setup-py', '--debug']
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/plazmaPC:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1429,unix/plazmaPC:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1429'
#     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg'
#     SSH_AGENT_LAUNCHER = 'gnome-keyring'
#     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'gnome-'
#     TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION = '1.87.2'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS_VSCODE_SNAP_ORIG = '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg'
#     GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'
#     GTK_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     GDK_BACKEND_VSCODE_SNAP_ORIG = ''
#     LANGUAGE = 'en_AU:en'
#     GIO_MODULE_DIR_VSCODE_SNAP_ORIG = ''
#     GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE = 'ubuntu'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
#     XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     BAMF_DESKTOP_FILE_HINT = '/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/code_code.desktop'
#     GTK_MODULES = 'gail:atk-bridge'
#     PWD = '/media/captaindeathead/HardDrive/PythonProjects/Farm_CEO'
#     GSETTINGS_SCHEMA_DIR = '/home/captaindeathead/snap/code/155/.local/share/glib-2.0/schemas'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu'
#     LOGNAME = 'captaindeathead'
#     GTK_EXE_PREFIX = '/snap/code/155/usr'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
#     GPG_AGENT_INFO = '/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
#     SYSTEMD_EXEC_PID = '1474'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority'
#     GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS = 'JS ERROR;JS LOG'
#     WINDOWPATH = '2'
#     HOME = '/home/captaindeathead'
#     USERNAME = 'captaindeathead'
#     LANG = 'en_AU.UTF-8'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.webp=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'Unity'
#     INVOCATION_ID = '3952f7f4c7a44edca819404e373c3b7b'
#     MANAGERPID = '1133'
#     CHROME_DESKTOP = 'code-url-handler.desktop'
#     GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT = 'stderr'
#     GSETTINGS_SCHEMA_DIR_VSCODE_SNAP_ORIG = ''
#     GTK_IM_MODULE_FILE_VSCODE_SNAP_ORIG = ''
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     XDG_SESSION_CLASS = 'user'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     GTK_PATH = '/snap/code/155/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     USER = 'captaindeathead'
#     GTK_PATH_VSCODE_SNAP_ORIG = ''
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     LOCPATH = '/snap/code/155/usr/lib/locale'
#     QT_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     GTK_EXE_PREFIX_VSCODE_SNAP_ORIG = ''
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS_VSCODE_SNAP_ORIG = '/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/home/captaindeathead/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     JOURNAL_STREAM = '8:34211'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/home/captaindeathead/snap/code/155/.local/share:/home/captaindeathead/snap/code/155:/snap/code/155/usr/share:/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/share/gnome:/home/captaindeathead/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     GDK_BACKEND = 'x11'
#     PATH = '/home/captaindeathead/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/captaindeathead/.local/bin:/home/captaindeathead/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin'
#     GDMSESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu:GNOME'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus'
#     GTK_IM_MODULE_FILE = '/home/captaindeathead/snap/code/common/.cache/immodules/immodules.cache'
#     LOCPATH_VSCODE_SNAP_ORIG = ''
#     GIO_MODULE_DIR = '/home/captaindeathead/snap/code/common/.cache/gio-modules'
#     GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE_PID = '25766'
#     GIO_LAUNCHED_DESKTOP_FILE = '/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/code_code.desktop'
#     TERM_PROGRAM = 'vscode'
#     _ = '/home/captaindeathead/.local/bin/buildozer'
#     OLDPWD = '/media/captaindeathead/HardDrive/PythonProjects'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/captaindeathead/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/captaindeathead/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/captaindeathead/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '31'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

I have tried python3.11, 3.10, 3.9, 3.8, 3.7 and wsl, lbuntu vm, ubuntu on my pc, google colab.

All of them have had the same error #longintrepr.h not found!